# Read deleted group owners with Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

Is there any way to list the owners of a recently deleted group with Graph API? I need to build a process with PowerAutomate to inform all the owners that their group is deleted.

With PowerShell I get this far:

```
Get-UnifiedGroup -Identity $guid -IncludeSoftDeletedGroups
```

Then I get a list of owners under the `ManagedBy` property, to bad, they are AD usernames only, not emails.

With Graph, I don't even get this far, I didn't find an an equivalent of the `IncludeSoftDeletedGroups` parameter and when I query for a deleted group I simply get an error that it doesn't exist. Can somebody please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.group
```

This is the call you need to do to get the recently deletedItems for groups(microsoft.graph.group). Please check this [DeletedItems Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Currently, there is no way to get the owners from deleted items, please raise the [UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests)